# python excersice: lists sums

Tags: python, arrays

i have this excesice:

*Given a list L, we indicate with  the generic element of L and with  the element in a symmetrical position to . Write it down a function examine_list which receives a list L of positive integers of even length and returns a boolean. In in particular, the function returns True if and only if, for each element  of L, the sum of the values of  and  is greater
the sum of the values of the elements positioned between  and .
Note that, when  and  are adjacent, the sum of the values of the elements positioned between  and  can be assumed equal to zero.
Example: If L = [12, 9, 7, 2, 1, 1, 3, 12] then the function returns True, because:

- 12 + 12> 9 + 7 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 3;
- 9 + 3> 7 + 2 + 1 + 1;
- 7 + 1> 2 + 1;
- 2 + 1> 0.*

My code is this:

```
def sum_list(l):
    list_sum = []
    pst_num = 0
    ult_num = -1
    for num in range(len(l)//2):
        list_sum.append(l[pst_num]+l[ult_num])
        pst_num +=1
        ult_num -=1
    return list_sum


def examine_list(l):
    somme_xd = sum_list(l)
    list_without_first_nums = []
    first = 1
    last = -1
    for n in range(len(l)//2):
        list_without_first_nums.append(l[first:last])
        first += 1
        last -= 1
 
    st_sum = 0
    count = 0
    for lists in range(len(list_without_first_nums)):
        for nums in range(len(list_without_first_nums[lists])):
            if somme_xd[st_sum] >= sum(list_without_first_nums[lists][nums]):
                st_sum += 1
                count += 1
                if count == len(somme_xd):
                    return True
            else:
                return False
                        
L = [12, 9, 7, 2, 1, 1, 3, 12]
examine_list(L)
```

I have created the `sum_list` who create a list of sums of the array.
my problem is the 2nd function: sum gives me always thid error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALESSA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 35, in <module>    
    examine_list(L)
  File "C:\Users\ALESSA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 26, in examine_list
    if somme_xd[st_sum] >= sum(list_without_first_nums[lists][nums]):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please include the error message in your post

Comment: yes, I'll add it right now

Comment: `somme_xd` is containing int. & you are accessing int variable as `somme_xd[st_sum]` which is not acceptable.

Comment: `list_without_first_nums` is a 2D list and you index it twice which gives elements. You can't `sum` a single element. You need an iterable. Maybe remove one level of indexing?

Comment: how i can do? @HarshaBiyani

Comment: @HarshaBiyani `somme_xd` is a list. The problem is not there...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Yes you are correct. Issue is with `sum(list_without_first_nums[lists][nums])`. Actually `list_without_first_nums[lists][nums]` is giving number and `sum(number)` is giving above error

Comment: @ski This is a bit beyond the scope of the question but your code is more complicated that it needs to be, maybe you can try to solve the problem by hand first and try to solve it in  a more simple manner

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion for this:

```
def examine_list(L):
    return not L or L[0]+L[-1]>sum(L[1:-1]) and examine_list(L[1:-1])

L = [12, 9, 7, 2, 1, 1, 3, 12]
print(examine_list(L)) # True
```

Or a comprehension with the all() function:

```
def examine_list(L):
    return all(L[i]+L[-1-i]>sum(L[i+1:-1-i]) for i in range(len(L)//2))
```

To avoid repeatedly adding subranges of the list (which is somewhat inefficient), you can do it in a loop that starts out with the total and progressively decreases it with the leftmost/rightmost items as it progresses inwards:

```
def examine_list(L):
    total = sum(L)
    for a,b in zip(L,reversed(L)):     # progress inwards from both sides
        total  -= a+b                  # reduce total to get sum in between
        if a+b <= total: return False  # not x+x' > in-between sum
        if total == 0: break           # reached middle, stop
    return True
```

Comment: could you explain me the second code? im a beginner

Comment: The `all()` function checks boolean values from an iterable and returns True if all the values are True.  The comprehension inside all(...) goes through indexes from 0 to the mid point of the list.  `L[i]+L[-1-i]` add up the element at position `i` with the element at the opposite position (i.e. x and x').  sum(L[i+1:-1-i]) adds all the elements in between those two.  So we get the comparison of x+x' < sum(in-between) for every position up to the middle (which must all be True)